# wget/curl/scrapy behave differently in aws

Tags: http, amazon-ec2, https, scrapy, wget

I was trying to use scrapy to crawl a website using my own machine (ubuntu or a mac) and a server in aws ec2 instance, I was able to using my own machine but not in aws.

And when I use wget or curl to the site, I was able to get the site download correctly on my own machine, but when it comes to aws, it returns status 200 but with an empty site. Inspecting wget with the debug info, it turns out my own machine has set-cookies but the aws does not.

when it's not working:

```
---response begin---
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Wed, 08 Nov 2023 05:52:27 GMT
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Content-Length: 0
Connection: keep-alive
Server: Apache
X-Cache: MISS from ip-xxx-xxx-xxx-xxx.us-west-1.compute.internal
X-Cache-Lookup: MISS from ip-xxx-xxx-xxx-xxx.us-west-1.compute.internal:3128
Via: 1.1 ip-xxx-xxx-xxx-xxx.us-west-1.compute.internal (squid/3.5.20)

---response end---
200 OK
Registered socket 3 for persistent reuse.
URI content encoding = ‘UTF-8’
Length: 0 [text/html]
Saving to: ‘items_a2a1.html’
```

when it's working:

```
---response begin---
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Wed, 08 Nov 2023 05:54:28 GMT
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Connection: keep-alive
Server: Apache
Set-Cookie: PHPSESSID=a75k7urjv7b6t1c42vj8g2tj2b; path=/; domain=xxx.com
Expires: Mon, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT
Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate
Pragma: no-cache
Set-Cookie: 633482dd2a9577b46bc89b1108a0f01e=cc8af61392da44a0a054f5ca6b83bc60; expires=Wed, 08-Nov-2023 17:54:27 GMT; Max-Age=43200; path=/; domain=xxx.com
Set-Cookie: xxx=deleted; expires=Thu, 01-Jan-1970 00:00:01 GMT; Max-Age=0; path=/; domain=xxx.com
Last-Modified: Wed, 08 Nov 2023 05:54:28 GMT
Cache-Control: post-check=0, pre-check=0
Set-Cookie: OSS=1; expires=Wed, 08-Nov-2023 10:54:28 GMT; Max-Age=18000; path=/
X-Cache: MISS from ip-xxx-xxx-xxx-xxx.us-west-1.compute.internal
X-Cache-Lookup: MISS from ip-xxx-xxx-xxx-xxx.us-west-1.compute.internal:3128
Via: 1.1 ip-1xxx-xxx-xxx-xxx.us-west-1.compute.internal (squid/3.5.20)

---response end---
```

I also tried creating new aws instance in different ubuntu version (ubuntu, linux or red hat) to make sure if anything inside of my instance messed up this, but the result is the same.

My question is, is the website capable of treating the ubuntu in aws differently than my own machine? if so, how could I test if that's the case, and if there's any workaround? if not, is there something setup differently in aws which causes this?
Thanks!

Comment: Are you using http or https? To prevent man-in-the-middle attacks, cookies are not sent over http. [Mozilla docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Cookies#restrict_access_to_cookies)

Comment: Good to know, I'm using https, actually when I tried to use http, the website gives me 302 and trying to direct me to https I guess. In regarding to that, I also used openssl to connect and try, but it was the same.